# matplotlib/pyplot: adding a text to a figure introduces an extra plot box in the subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to save a figure containing a title, two plots stacked vertically (with their own titles) and a text to the right of the two plots. This is the code I have right now:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,5))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.6, top=0.85)
fig.suptitle(filename,fontsize=15,x=0.75)
    
# Print the text
plt.text(1.1,0.25,fig_text)
    
# Zoomed in plot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.title.set_text("First quadrant")
ax1.set_xlabel('Voltage (mV)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Current (mA cm$^{-2}$)')
ax1.plot(V,C)
ax1.plot(Vmpp,Cmpp,marker='o',markersize=3,color="red")
ax1.axhline(0,color='k',lw=1)
ax1.axvline(0,color='k',lw=1)
ax1.set_ylim(J_min,J_max)
ax1.set_xlim(-50,V_max)
    
# Full JV scan plot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.title.set_text("Full JV scan")
ax2.set_xlabel('Voltage (mV)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Current (mA cm$^{-2}$)')
ax2.plot(V,C)
ax2.axhline(0,color='k',lw=1)
ax2.axvline(0,color='k',lw=1)
    
plt.savefig(output_dir+filename+'.jpg',pil_kwargs{'quality':20},dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close(fig)
```

if I comment out the `plt.text(1.1,0.25,fig_text)` line everything gets printed as expected:

[Figure without text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLEEE.jpg)

However, if I uncomment that line to actually print the text I want, a new plot box appears with 0 < x,y < 1 that encompasses both subplots plot boxes, creating a big mess:

[Figure with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDu8Y.jpg)

Does anyone know why this happens and how to stop it?

Comment: you are adding the text before you add any subplot axes, so matplotlib is creating one for you automatically at that point (hence the box). You could either use the [`plt.figtext()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figtext.html) function, or use `plt.text` or `ax1.text` after you have created your subplot axes.

Comment: Of course... why didn't I think of this myself? It was late in the night, but... Anyway, problem solved - thanks @tmdavison